# How to keep data in react after browser back

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, gatsby, reach-router

I have a React app(`Gatsby`) and using `@reach/router`.
There are multiple pages like user page, follower page...etc.
Fetching data in useEffect hook and here is the problem.

When I navigate to another page from the current page, I'm passing a param, sending it to the next component, for example to a user page, then calling API in useEffect hook in the component with the param. Then you can go to another component like follower page with a param, calling api in useEffect again.
When I try to go back with browser back, the previous data updates again. Ideally I don't want it to get updated every time when I go back to the previous page.

I understand that this happens because I'm calling it in the useEffect hook. Thought about passing data as props with `navigate` (ex. `navigate("/follower", state: { data })`), but I think navigate to the page first and fetching data is the best solution for users because when fetching data is taking some time, I want to show skeleton or a loading indicator in the next page. The ideal experience is something like twitter.
Not sure this isn't working because I'm using `@reach/router` instead of `react-router-dom`

Any advise is appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Apologise for my poor explanation.
My problem here is when I keep going back to previous pages like this `user page` → `follower` → `(another)user` → `follower ...` , browser doesn't remember what were there and useEffect fires everytime. It wasn't happening with react-router before?

My guess is that since I'm using GatsbyJS(SSR) and client-side routing, somehow it generates pages every time even the browser back triggered instead painting it again? I'm not familiar with SSR w/ cliet-routing, hoping to get some info somewhere..

Comment: Sounds like you need React.memo to memorize the given props and tell the component to stop re-render if the props are the same, no?

Comment: @Delice Thanks for the comment! Haven't used memo yet. Will try it out. But my problem is browser doesn't remember previous state when you keep going back to previous pages

Answer (score 0):

The only way it comes to my mind is using local storage or cookies, within a `useEffect` with `deps` (`[]`), otherwise, each rendering of the page (moving back and forward for example) will trigger again all side-effects available.

Alternatively, you can use `useEffect`'s `deps`, to only fire the `useEffect` if the needed dependency has changed.

```
const SomePage=(props)=>{

const isLoggedIn=props.isLoggedIn || localStorage.getItem('logIn')

useEffect(()=>{
// this will only be fired when yourDeps changes

}, [yourDeps])

return {isLoggedIn ? <div>Hello ${user}</div> : <Link to="/log-in">Log in</Link>

}
```

You `deps` (`yourDeps`) can also check values that you are sending through the location state or from local storate/cookies.

You can also use `useRef` hook to store "old" values from references but given your generic explanation, I'm not sure which case fits you better.